# How to make a print option with jquery data table plugin

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using following codes for making table as grid

```
oTable = $('#search_table').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sScrollY": "200px",
    "bPaginate": true,
    //"bAutoWidth": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    "oTableTools": {
        "aButtons": [{
            "sExtends": "print",
            "sMessage": "Generated by DataTables"
        }]
    },
    "aoColumns": [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null, {
            "bSortable": false
        }, {
            "bSortable": false
        },
        null,
    ]
});
```

**Question:** I need to print the table which is used in datatable plugins. whether any option for print is there with data table plugin.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This add–on might help you: http://www.datatables.net/extras/tabletools/

> TableTools is a plug-in for the DataTables HTML table enhancer, which adds a highly customisable button toolbar to a DataTable. Key features include:
>
> - Copy to clipboard
> - Save table data as CSV, XLS or PDF files
> - Print view for clean printing
> - Row selection options
> - Easy use predefined buttons
> - Simple customisation of buttons
> - Well defined API for advanced control...